# Grep value from multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, xargs

I have a file named A.nam (ten thousands lines) with some coordinates i.e.

> K6662028
>
> K6703908
>
> K6605560

I have to grep it from 900 files with nine column (B1.txt....B900.txt). I want these coordinates to be searched in all files (I already know all files have these) and then I wish to grep three columns of interest. My one liner-worked well with one file but for 900 files I guess I have to loop, but how?

My one-liner is

```
cat A.nam |xargs -i grep -P '{}' B1.txt |awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$9}' > test.txt
```

I will appreciate if anybody can help.

Comment: There isn't quite enough information here for me to test a solution. Could you provide a couple of sample input files (B1.txt and B2.txt for example), a few lines each, along with the output you'd expect from the eventual solution? BTW, this is called creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in StackOverflow jargon. :)

Comment: When you say `I wish to grep three columns` do you mean a) you want to look only in those columns for strings matching your regexp, or b) you want to look for your regexp across the whole line but only output those columns or c) something else? Should the match be full or partial? [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output to get the best help.

Comment: @Ed Morton well you are right I want to look for this regexp across the whole line but only output these columns. match should be exact match  "K6662028" for every thing in A.nam

Comment: @ghoti B*.txt files have this format                                                                       1                        K6662028    8    Y        SIT      78  0.3      0.2      0.99      so i want 1\tK6662028\t0.99

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input (i.e. the strings you're looking for **in context**) and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Nice job on your one liner. You can make one small change to it and it will work great.

The `cat` command, when given multiple files, cats them to the stdout one after another, so `cat a b` will `cat` file `a` followed by file `b`, as if they were one file.

For example, if I have 200 files that are all like `1001.out`, `1002.out`, `1003.out` ... `1200.out` I can `cat` all of them as so: `cat 1*.out`

So if, for example, your files are all some combination of B at the start and .txt at the end, like your `B1.txt`...`B900.txt` example , your one liner can be changed as so:

`cat B*.txt |xargs -i grep -P '{}' B1.txt |awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$9}' > test.txt`

Comment: I think OP is saying that `B*.txt` is the set of multiple files, and there is only one `A.nam`.

Comment: Just reread the question, thanks for pointing that out. I'll update the answer.

Comment: You have mistaken I guess there are 900 files `B*.txt`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. yes there are 900 files B*.txt A.nam is one

Comment: The 200 is just an example, I'm explaining the theory so that you know this will work not just for your situation but for any grouping of files.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` can take a filename containing patterns, the `-f` option. I think you want

```
grep -F -w -f A.nam B*.txt | awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $1, $2, $9}' > test.txt
```

I'm thinking you want `-F` to specify your patterns are fixed strings not regexes, and `-w` to force the strings to match whole words.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but this i have used already and it gives desired outut in rows and i want in column